# Cannot create a project within the Flutter SDK. Target directory 'C:\src\flutter\test_instalasi_flutter' is within the Flutter SDK at 'C:\src\flutter'

Tags: flutter, dart

> [test_instalasi_flutter] flutter create --template app --overwrite .
> Cannot create a project within the Flutter SDK. Target directory
> 'C:\src\flutter\test_instalasi_flutter' is within the Flutter SDK at
> 'C:\src\flutter'. exit code 2

hi! i'm newbie, please help me.
when creating a new Flutter in visual studio code, the library folder doesn't show up. But when I create a new Dart library it exists and appears, how do you flutter it ?. thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to create your project inside the same directory as the Flutter SDK? Create your project inside of another directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your directory different than the `FLUTTER SDK` directory (don't use this: `C:\src\flutter`)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all is installed:

1. Java
2. Flutter SDK
3. Android Studio

- Proceed to open Android Studio
- Create a new flutter project
- In the flutter option choose the path to the install location of the sdk
  ex C:\src\flutter\flutter
- Now have a new install location folder (new) and have it in the c drive

Answer (score -1):

Just change the location where you're saving the project( Save it to a new directory) and you'