# flutter new project directory error message

Tags: flutter

The message "Cannot create a project with in the Flutter SDK" came out and it was resolved when I created a new project in a directory outside the flutter. What is the reason for this kind of problem?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70578138/cannot-create-a-project-within-the-flutter-sdk-target-directory-c-src-flutter

Comment: I know the solution to this problem and I solved it. But I want to know why this problem is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is given out when you try to create a flutter project inside the flutter SDK. Creating a project inside the SDK is not supported.

Error message is there so that people would not be able to create a project inside the SDK.

This would be the basic idea, I am not able to give any other reasons without more information.